# counting proof for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{k} = 2^n - 1$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I was hoping someone could help me come up with a combinatorial proof, one with an easy to understand 'story' for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{k} = 2^n - 1$. For instance I understand that $2^n$ is the number of possibilities when creating subsets of size $n$. For example, if you're given a choice of any topping on a pizza, and you can only have said topping once (decide to include or exclude) then you have $2^n$ choices. But I'm not sure how the $-1 $ would be incorporated, or why the LHS would be $1+2+4+8+...+2^{n-1}$

Comment: Well, If you can have $m$ toppings and you are not allowed to have a plain pizza then... If you can have $K_m$ types with $m$ toppings, and then someone gives you a new $m+1$ topping how many extra pizzas can you make.  All your new pizzas have the new topping and they may or may not have any of the old $m$ toppings.  So there are $2^m$ new pizza types.  So if $K_m$ is the number of pizzas with $m$ toppings, then $K_{m+1} = K_{m} + 2^m$ is the number with $m+1$ toppings.    But $K_m$ mus be $2^{m-1} + K_{m-1}$ and so on.  And $K_0$ is $0$ as we aren't allowed to not have toppings so ....$

Comment: $K_{m+1} = 2^m +2^{m-1} + .... + 2^0$.  But we can figure logically that if we have $m+1$ toppings there are $2^{m+1}$ pizzas but if we subtract the type with no toppings. we have $K_{m+1} = 2^{m+1} -1 = 2^m + 2^{m-1} + .... + 2^0$.

Comment: The $-1$ is an offset.  You have a the sum $2^m + 2^{m-1} + .... + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1$.  If you add $1$ to that you.... set off an avalanch.  The $1$ adds to the one and you get $2$.  That add to the $2$ and you get $4$.  That $4$ adds to the $4$ and you get $8$.  And so on.... or if you have $2^m$ you can split it in half.  And get two $2^{m-1}$.  Yo split that in half, and take one of the resulting $2^{m-1}$s and split it in half and so on.... eventually you get a $4$ and split it to two $2$s and you split the $2$ into two $1$ and you take a $1$ and... throw it away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sides count the number of games in a single-elimination tournament with $2^n$ teams.  The left side counts the number of games by round, and the right side is obtained by noting that all teams but the winner lose one game each.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense actually, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

How many strings of $0$s and $1$s of length $n$ are there which have at least one $1$?

- There are $2^n$ strings total, except we want to omit the string of all $0$'s, so $2^n-1$.
- Consider the location of the rightmost $1$, at spot $k$, for some $k\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Given the rightmost $1$ is at spot $k$, the first $k-1$ spaces can be chosen in $2^{k-1}$ ways, while the rest of the string is then forced (since there are only $0$'s to the right of the rightmost $1$). Summing over $k$, the number of strings is $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k}$.

Equating the two answers, you get $2^n-1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k$.

---

Don't get too caught up with trying to come up with a "story" involving pizza or children or candy or committees; this can obscure the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are not allowed to have a pizza with no toppings.

Then if you have $m$ possible toppings you are allowed to have $2^m -1$ toppings. (For any type of topping you can or can not include it.  That is $2^m$ choices. But that includes excluding every topping and having a pizza with no toppings.  That's not allowed so you are allowed $2^m -1$ types of pizzas.)

Now what if you choice was $0$ toppings how many pizzas can you have?  Well, zero.

And if you had one topping how many?  Well, $1$.

Okay, now let's say I gave you a *new* topping.  How many *more* new types of pizzas could you *add* to the number you could already make?

Well, every new type will have the new topping.  And of the $m$ old toppings I can either include it or not.  So that is $2^m$ *new* types.

So if I get a second topping I can make $2^1$ new pizzas and now make $1+2$ types of pizzas.

And if I get a third topping I can make $2^2$ new pizzas and now make $1+ 2 + 4$ types of pizzas.

....

And if I get an $m$th toppin I can make $2^{m-1}$ new types of pizzas and now can make $1+2+4+ .... + 2^{m-1}$.

SO by those two different calculations I figure if I have $m$ toppings I can have $2^m-1$ different types or $1  + 2+ 4+ ..... + 2^{m-1}$ different types.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it