# Combinatorial proof that $2^{n+1}-1=1+2+4+\dots+2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, exponentiation, combinatorial-proofs

Let $S_k$ be a set with $k$ elements. Then $S_k$ has $2^k$ subsets. So the formula $2^{n+1}-1 = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k$ can be translated to
$$\text{number of *nonempty* subsets of $S_{n+1}$} = \sum_{k=0}^n\text{number of subsets of $S_{k}$}.$$
Is there a combinatorial way of seeing that this formula must hold?

---

(I'm not looking for non-combinatorial proofs like $(2-1)\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1}-1$)

Comment: Hint:\begin{align}&\text{number of non-zero $(n+1)$-digit binary words}\\=&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\text{number of k-digit binary words with leading $1$}\end{align}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The idea behind the sum of powers of 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990137/the-idea-behind-the-sum-of-powers-of-2) - combinatorial proof by Foobaz John.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I think so. Thanks!

Comment: I've posted a new answer on the old question, giving a proof technique it looks like they missed until now, despite its being well-known.

Comment: @J.G. very nice proof, I think this is the closest so far to what I was looking for

Comment: Please see my combinatorial proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365993/counting-proof-for-sum-k-0n-1-2k-2n-1/3366148#3366148).